# Translate strings into corresponding values

Tags: php, string, algorithm

Let's say I have this table of correspondance :

```
'AZERTY' -  10
'QSDFGH' - 20
'WXCVBN' - 8
'UIOP' - 47
```

By hardcoding the value and the string associated can I translate this string :

```
'AZERTY,QSDFGH,WXCVBN,UIOP'
to  
'10,20,8,47'
```

In PHP ?

And how ?

Comment: are the ints ids in a db table/keys in an array/properties in an object?

Comment: Yes, yes you can.

Comment: any piece of code you have been trying?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs No, I just know what string corresponds to what value, and I need something like if it is this string than give me this value

Comment: Pass an array to `str_replace`?

Comment: @m then there are many a way you can achieve, all of which can be found at http://php.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let us fetch the values in the table to an array.

```
$main_array1= ["AZERTY", "QSDFGH", "WXCVBN", "UIOP"];

$main_array2= [10, 20, 8, 47 ];
```

Next say we input this string which needs to be translated to that number:

```
$input_string = "AZERTY,QSDFGH,WXCVBN,UIOP";
```

Now we will convert this input string to an array.

```
$input_array=explode(",",$input_string);
```

Now we can loop through all the elements in the input array and display the desired output.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($input_array); $i++){
     for($j=0; $j<count($main_array1); $j++){
         if($input_array[$i]==$main_array1[$j]){
            echo $main_array2[$j] . ",";
         }
     }
}
```

This will gives us the output of 10,20,8,47